# Cross moments of multinomial distribution

Tags: probability

Let $X = (X_1,X_2,\dots,X_k) \sim \operatorname{Multinomial}(N,\pi)$ where $\pi = (p_1,\dots,p_k)$.

Is there a general formula for $\mathbb{E} X_i^m X_j^n$ when $i \neq j$?

The joint MGF of $(X_i,X_j)$ can be seen to be $\phi_{X_i,X_j}(x,y) = (p_1 e^x + p_2e^y+ 1-p_1-p_2)^N.$ But obtaining $\mathbb{E} X_i^m X_j^n$ using this is tedious except for small values of $m$ and $n$.

[Note: Changed question since I was able to verify using CAS]
For example one can use Maxima to check that using the MGF $\mathbb{E} X_i^2X_j^2 =  (N - 3) (N - 2) (N - 1) N p_i^2  p_j^2 + (N - 2) (N - 1) N  p_i p_j(p_i+p_j) + (N-1)Np_ip_j$

Answer (score 1):

One way to make your work easier is to derive the following formulas. Write $\Phi_N(x,y) \equiv \mathbb{E}[\exp(x X_1 + y X_2)]$, then

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial x} \Phi_N(x,y) = N p_1 e^x \Phi_{N-1}(x,y)$$

and

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial y} \Phi_N(x,y) = N p_2 e^y \Phi_{N-1}(x,y)$$

This will keep your work tidy when computing derivatives.